# AAPT: error: unexpected element <profileable> found in <manifest><application>

Tags: android, aapt

AAPT: error: unexpected element `<profileable>` found in `<manifest><application>`

According to the document:https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/profileable-element

Supposed that `<profileable>` contained in `<Application>` is legal, but failed in APK packaging stage, aapt abort.

```
<manifest ...>
    <application ...>
      <profileable android:shell="true" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

```
ext.versions = [
        'compileSdkVersion': 31,
        'buildToolsVersion': '30.0.2',
        'minSdkVersion'    : 29,
        'targetSdkVersion' : 29,
        'kotlin'           : '1.3.50',
    ]
```

```
androidGradlePlugin: "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2"
```

Updated: problems solved! Thanks @CommonsWare, by updated AGP to 4.0.0 this problem can be solved!

Comment: What is your question? AFAIK, the manifest does not offer a `<profileable>`, and the error suggests that the build tools are not aware of that element either. Perhaps you could delete the element.

Comment: @CommonsWare even i dont get this element under application tag but doc says this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/profileable-element

Comment: @Wini: Interesting -- I missed when they added that. Thanks for pointing it out! Perhaps the OP's project has a `compileSdkVersion` below 29, has an old `buildToolsVersion`, or has an old Android Gradle Plugin.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the fast reply, I've updated the description. 'compileSdkVersion': 31, 'buildToolsVersion': '30.0.2','minSdkVersion'    : 29,'targetSdkVersion' : 29, androidGradlePlugin3.5.2

Comment: @CommonsWare Update AGP to 4.0 this problem will be solved, thanks for the suggestion, but still have doubt in why there is a impact for AGP on AAPT compiler.

Comment: @CommonsWare In other world, in my old misconceptions, AAPT is only decided by build tools.But in fact, changing the AGP to 4.0 above is the only solution. What's more, even I change the AAPT version in build script, doesn't works either.

Comment: @lirui i have updated my code as per your gradle versions...but still my manifest didnt detect `profilable` ?why?

Comment: @Wini Make sure Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0 above, 3.5.2 in the question description is WRONG.

Comment: @lirui  i used AGP 4.0.0 only still it doesnt detect `profilable` in manifest

Comment: "doesnt detect profilable in manifest", is this mean the same AAPT error in apk pacakging with me ?

Comment: @lirui Im getting this Element profileable is not allowed here  in manifest –